# Use custom column field in mobile selector

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom field called 'UsrAlternateIDs' to be used for filtering in selector fields in page like this:
[image]

And I want same fields to be used in mobile app for selecting inventory item using the field 'AlternateIDs'.
[image]

This is what I did to use the field in selector for Inventory Item but it is not working.
[image]

Is there anything else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should be using **AlternateIDs** instead of **UsrAlternateIDs** in mapping file.

Either sample from below should add the Alternative IDs column to Inventory Item lookup on a mobile device when placed in your Acumatica website `\App_Data\Mobile\` folder:

- by using XML file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <sm:SiteMap xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sm:Folder DisplayName="Sales Orders" Icon="system://Cash" IsDefaultFavorite="true" Type="HubFolder">
      <sm:Screen DisplayName="Sales Orders" Icon="system://Cash" Id="SO301000" ExpandSelector="OrderType" Type="SimpleScreen">
        <sm:Container Name="DocumentDetails" FieldsToShow="9" ContainerActionsToExpand="1" ListActionsToExpand="0" FormActionsToExpand="1">
          <sm:Field Name="InventoryID" ListPriority="98">
            <sm:SelectorContainer FieldsToShow="3">
              <sm:Field Name="InventoryID"/>
              <sm:Field Name="Description"/>
              <sm:Field Name="AlternateIDs"/>
            </sm:SelectorContainer>
          </sm:Field>
        </sm:Container>
      </sm:Screen>
    </sm:Folder>
  </sm:SiteMap>
  ```
- or with the use of MSDL:

  ```
  update screen "SO301000" {
    update container "DocumentDetails" {
      update field "InventoryID" {
        selector {
          fieldsToShow = 3
          add field "InventoryID"
          add field "Description" 
          add field "AlternateIDs" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

And this is how the final result should look on Android and iOS:
[image]
[image]